# Importing variables that are constantley changing from another python file

Tags: python-2.7

I want to read a CSV file which is being constantly updated and is writing new lines. So every time there is a new line I am catching `var5`. `instrument` and `quantity` are fixed values.

How can I import and use   `var5`, `instrument` and `quantity`  variables in another Python file?

```
import time
import os

filename = 'myfile.csv'
mycsv = open(filename, 'r')
#   Find the size of the file and move to the end
mycsv.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)


while 1:
   time.sleep(1)
   where = mycsv.tell()
   line = mycsv.readline()

   if not line:
      mycsv.seek(where)
   else:
      arr_line = line.split(',')
      var5 = arr_line[5]
      instrument = "myinstrument"
      quantity = 1000
      return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us suppose the module in which you have coded the above program is called `module1.py`

Create a new module called `module2.py` in which you must type: `import module1`

You can then access those variables from `module2.py` this way:

```
module1.var5
module1.instrument
module1.quantity
```

Since `instrument` and `quantity` are fixed value variables, it is more efficient to declare their values before the `while` loop and rename them following  [**PEP 8**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#constants):

```
INSTRUMENT = "myinstrument"
QUANTITY = 1000
```

This is an excellent method to avoid namespace conflicts. Updating `var5` variable's value in `module1.py` will be reflected in `module2.py`. The two other constants' value will remain the same.

Comment: Thats working fine thanks. But when I try to import more modules for example I have module1.py, module2.py and module3.py  and they all have var5 inside I only get the var5 from the first module. For example print module1.var5, module2.var5, module3.var5 I only get the value from module1,var5. Is it possible to import more than one module?

Comment: Yes, you can import as much modules you want into an other module.

Comment: Why is that when I have imported the variable I cannot use it for example in if condition. All I see on my console is the output of module1.py

Comment: Ask a different question with an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)